# How to convert Html bootstrap Theme to Yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, themes

I am new programmer and I want make a new E-Shop
i download this theme:
live demo : http://www.bootstrappage.com/view/boots_shop/
Source: http://www.templatescreme.com/downloading/bootshop-bootstrap-responsive-shopping-template

This is a Html responsive bootstrap theme
but I am very confuse how can I change this template to Yii theme

as u know i search and i know i should make a newfolder on   webroot/theme/Custome-theme
and then change webroot/protected/config/main.php
add this line:'theme'=>'Custome-theme'

This above process its very good work on yii theme and i test a lot of times but I need change HTML tempelate to yii theme

please help me very soon

Comment: You can't convert bootstrap to yii but you can implement [yii bootstrap extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap) in your project and then call/include your own bootstrap themes.

Answer (score 0):

as Rohit Suthar commented you cant just convert html template into yii theme,
for the first step you should know [how yii works](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/250/yii-for-beginners/), [what is MVC](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/), and [how yii views works](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view).

in yii the template is just a "wrapper" for the views which are the basic way to display something, in your case they will display the shop theme.

just to make sure - all the information bellow is based on yii version 1.1, there is newer version of yii(yii 2) which is better to learn(in my opinion) if you have no experience with yii yet.

also i am rely on that you have experience with php and html(at least), so if not i suggest you start with searching some information about them.

if you do not have any experience with php,html,yii and just want to create e-commerce website for yourself i would suggest you to try [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) with [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/)